# Android internal NPE in ViewGroup dispatchAttachedToWindow

Tags: android, android-layout, nullpointerexception

Does anyone knows how to solve the following `bug` ?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2434)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2434)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2434)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2434)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2434)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1313)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1110)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4484)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4856)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

I got it a few times on **Android** `4.1` devices when the app is coming back from the background.

Comment: I am setting a few variables and mainly checking for GooglePlayServices availability as shown here: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html#sample-play

Comment: One of our beta tester got it on orientation changed

Answer (score 0):

You get this only on 4.1v?
Seems that your rootview or your windows is unavailable, we need more coder/log info to get better results.

If so, there isn't a bug, you need to check for your views not null, maybe the GC has quit your view so you get this error.

Please tell us more info, when happens, frequently?, how many time has pass from background?, and so on